# How to find max and min values

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, interpolation, periodic-function

Need to find max and min values like on pic. 
I am wondering how I could determine max and min values of oscillations ? How could I find these values:
[image]
My code:

```
<< PhysicalConstants`
<< Units`

Subscript[I, critical] = 10 *10^-3(*Milli Ampere*);
c = 1.2*10^-13 (*Farad*);
Subscript[R, N] = 50*10^-3 (*Milli Ohm*);
η = 1.2; 
h = PlanckConstantReduced*1/(Joule Second);
e = ElectronCharge*1/Coulomb;
Subscript[t, 0] = 0;
Subscript[t, 1] = 1*10^-11;

Subscript[ω, c] = η*((2 e)/h)*Subscript[I, critical]*Subscript[R, N];
β = 2 e/h*Subscript[I, critical]*c*(Subscript[R, N])^2;
Subscript[I, dc] = Subscript[I, critical]*1.5;
b = Subscript[I, dc]/Subscript[I, critical];

eq = NDSolve[{N[β/Subscript[ω, c]^2]*φ''[t] + 
N[1/Subscript[ω, c]]*φ'[t] + Sin[φ[t]] - b == 0, 
φ'[0] == 0, φ[0] == Pi/2}, φ, {t, Subscript[t, 0],  Subscript[t, 1]}]; 

Plot[N[h/(2 e)*Evaluate[φ'[t] /. eq][[1]]], {t, Subscript[t, 0], 
Subscript[t, 1]}, PlotStyle -> Orange, PlotLegends -> {"V(t)"}, 
AxesLabel -> {"t,s", "V(t)"}]
```

Comment: What version are you using? Those two packages you loaded aren't needed anymore in the current version. Also: you could use `WhenEvent[]` so that the extrema are returned while you are solving your differential equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following extracts all `Line` objects from the plot, and selects all `y`-coordinates form the first (and only) from these objects. In the end, we simply apply `MinMax`.

```
plot = Plot[
   N[h/(2 e)*Evaluate[φ'[t] /. eq][[1]]], {t, 
    Subscript[t, 0], Subscript[t, 1]}, PlotStyle -> Orange, 
   PlotLegends -> {"V(t)"}, AxesLabel -> {"t,s", "V(t)"}];

MinMax[Cases[plot, _Line, All][[1, 1, All, 2]]]
```

> {1.22445*10^-8, 0.00149979}

Starting the list a bit later (because the beginning seems to contain bad data) yields

```
MinMax[Cases[plot, _Line, All][[1, 1, 10 ;;, 2]]]
```

> {0.000298883, 0.00149979}

Alternatively, you may use `Maximize` and `Minimize` directly on the function that you have plotted:

```
epsilon = 10^-12;
Maximize[{N[h/(2 e)*Evaluate[φ'[t] /. eq][[1]]], 
  Subscript[t, 0] <= t <= Subscript[t, 1]}, t]
Minimize[{N[h/(2 e)*Evaluate[φ'[t] /. eq][[1]]], 
  Subscript[t, 0] + epsilon <= t <= Subscript[t, 1]}, t]
```

> {0.00149984, {t -> 1.55926*10^-12}}
>
> {0.000300006, {t -> 3.09243*10^-12}}

Comment: `PeakDetect[]` can also be used on the raw data produced by `Plot[]`.